# Simple jQuery Image Zoom - Overflow outsize browser window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I put together this simplified version of a little image zoom script I am working on.

https://jsfiddle.net/cvanderlinden/jjrhgxvv/4/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="image-zoom">
  <div class="zoom--actions">
    <a href="#" class="zoom-in">Zoom In</a>
    <a href="#" class="zoom-out">Zoom In</a>
  </div>
  <div class="zoom--img">
    <img src="https://www.google.ca/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS (jQuery):**

```
$('.zoom--actions .zoom-in').on('click', function () {
        var img = $(this).parents('.image-zoom').find('.zoom--img img');
        var width = img.width();
        var newWidth = width + 100;
        img.width(newWidth);
    }
);
$('.zoom--actions .zoom-out').on('click', function () {
        var img = $(this).parents('.image-zoom').find('.zoom--img img');
        var width = img.width();
        var newWidth = width - 100;
        img.width(newWidth);
    }
);
```

It's working as intended, the only problem I have found is that, it only seems to want to zoom until the window width has been reached, at which point it stops. It doesn't seem to matter on the jsfiddle, but inside a real browser, it stops.  How do I allow the image to go past the browser window width, and also hide scrolling, just let the overflow happen.

Comment: it seems that some of css rule limits on image enlargement. If you add the style: `img {
  max-width: 100%;
}` to your fiddle you'll get the same effect. So you need to check you stylesheet or provide it over here. https://jsfiddle.net/banzay52/d2jaxbbn/

Comment: Thanks Banzay! That was it!

Comment: Moved it to the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that some of css rule limits on image enlargement.
If you add the style:

```
img { max-width: 100%; }
```

to your fiddle, you'll get the same effect.
So you need to examine you stylesheet for similar rule existence.
Here is a fiddle demo  [issue](http://jsfiddle.net/banzay52/d2jaxbbn)

Answer (score 0):

simple css will do the trick : `body{overflow-x: visible;}`

Comment: That was my first guess, but it doesn't seem to do anything.  Tried it on body and parent elements.  Still stopping at the window width.

Comment: edited my answer, didnt understand your question before

Comment: Unfortunately, the same result.

Answer (score -1):

I am new to html so i'm not the best but try this code! Switch up the ID's and source links, I am using a Pikachu card image as a test!

```html
<!DOCTYPEhtml>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#pikachu-card {
border: 3px solid black;
}

#pikachu-card:hover {
width: 400px;
height: 546px;
border: 6px solid black;
}
</style>
<title>
Test
</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hover to zoom</h1>
<img src="http://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/thumb/7/78/PikachuBaseSet58.png/200px-PikachuBaseSet58.png" id="pikachu-card">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.